# StackOverflowError while reading then deleting object with hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring, stack-overflow

I am reading an objects and then simply deleting it and it throws java.lang.StackOverflowError!

```
public class TestDummy extends TestCase {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private AccountDao accountDao;



public void testDeleteAccount(){

        Account acc = accountDao.get("9BE4BFA718EA4B4EE044000077B05A84");
        System.out.println("Account name is "+acc.getAccountName());
        accountDao.delete(a);

    }
```

}

accountDao and context are instantiating good.

here is get() and delete() methods

```
   public Account get(String id) {
    Account acc = getHibernateTemplate().get(Account.class, id);
    return  acc;
}

public void delete(Account account) {
    delete(account);
}
```

I wonder what can be recursively happening here!

Please advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void delete(Account account) 
{
   delete(account);
}
```

No wonder you get SO.

Comment: I see no delete at all. You are just making recursive call.

Comment: Oh i see....  I was intending to call delete() of hibernate template. I'll change. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Recursion causing stack to overflow is shamelessly hidden here:

```
public void delete(Account account) {
    delete(account);
}
```

Comment: Tks.  My bad.. I ment to call delete from HibernateTemplate